# How to get the text before any numeric or special characters?

Tags: c#

I need to parse a string and return only the alphabetic characters before the first non-letter character.

**Example 1:**

If the text is  -  `John 123`

Expected Result is  -  `John`

**Example 2:**

If the text is  -  `Anthony (Manager)`

Expected Result is  -  `Anthony`

Comment: If you have tried something, Expected Result is - to see your code

Comment: what should happen when text is `john123` ?

Comment: @sachin That result should  be "John".

Answer (score 4):

Go for the easy solution, mate:

```
var str = "Anthony (Manager)";
var res = str.TakeWhile(c => Char.IsLetter(c));
```

Edit: Just realized you also need the spaces:

```
var str = "Anthony Hopkins (Actor)";
var res = str.TakeWhile(c => Char.IsLetter(c) || Char.IsWhiteSpace(c));
```

Answer (score 0):

So far it seems a simple `Regex` would solve your problem:

```
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z]+");
        string expected = reg.Match(input).Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string on space delimeter and take the first element:

```
var firstName = myStr.Split().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I need the space . FOr example, If the text is "stack over 123 flow" I need the result should be "stack over"

Comment: In that case, use regexp